# Weird backlinks from host name instead of FQDN

Tags: vps, wordpress, dns-zone

Writing here with the hope anyone can help or has similar issue.

I recently moved my website to a new VPS. After week or two I started receiving backlinks from my host name, which is counted in google search console as external backlinks. This is wrong and potentially bad for SEO.

I do have approximately 720 (~same number of pages) backlinks from the virtual host name which is `tamibg.dedivirt1149.your-server.de`, and google counts this as a backlink from `your-server.de` while this should be my own domain tami.bg and not listed under external backlinks.

I doubt this is a mistake, and the virtual host is not translated to my own domain host `tami.bg`. The CMS is Wordpress and I know that at some time, it looks for FQDN to serve the domains under it operates. For some reason it finds the virtual host name instead FQDN `tami . bg` the virtual host address above does not configure either in database or in files. I did a search.

Pls if some is expert in VPS and DNS and can help, I will be grateful.

Thanks,
Pavel